# Problem when installing pods after updating React Native

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I have recently tried updating my react native from 0.62 to 0.63.

After doing this I went into my iOS folder via cd iOS and ran pod install, when doing this I get the following error message in my terminal.

[image: error]

[image: error]

I have tried running the command pod repo update as the error says but this doesn't fix the problem.

I have tried searching the error online but am unable to find a fix.

Here is my profile file.

```html
platform :ios, '10.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'Example' do
  # Pods for Example
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  # React Native Maps dependencies
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'


  pod 'RNCPushNotificationIOS', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios'

  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'

  target 'ExampleTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'Example-tvOS' do
  # Pods for AntrimElimChurch-tvOS

  target 'Example-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end


  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to upgrade pod file as there are lots of changes from 62 to 63.

Here is sample for RN 63
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/release/0.63.0-rc.1/RnDiffApp/ios/Podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'RnDiffApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'RnDiffAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'RnDiffApp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RnDiffApp-tvOS

  target 'RnDiffApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I my case, I just changed these lines. At the `Podfile` and it's fixed my issue.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

TO

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Comment: Huff!!
Saved by this !!
Spent so many hours to solve this !!
Thanks
I have upvoted as well

Answer (score 2):

I had to update folly pods to

```
pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

from

```
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to update my Podfile spec reference to fix this, specifically for call invoker.

**to this**: pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"

from this: pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE for RN 0.64.0 :**

I ran into similar problem when I upgraded my project RN to 0.64.0. The `podfile` was not installing. So I `deintegrate` pod and deleted pod file.

```
rm podfile
pod deintegrate
```

Then I created new empty project. Took its `podfile` and replace it with mine.

Please check my old/new file.

**Old Podfile:**

```
   require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
   require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
    platform :ios, '10.0'
    
    pre_install do |installer|
      puts("Image fix for ios14: remove this when upgradeing to >= 0.63.3")
      find = "_currentFrame.CGImage;"
      replace = "_currentFrame.CGImage ;} else { [super displayLayer:layer];"
      op = `sed -ie "s/#{find}/#{replace}/" ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m`
      puts("Image fix for ios14 done")
    end
    
    
    target 'Fomoyolo' do
      config = use_native_modules!
    
      use_react_native!(
        :path => config[:reactNativePath],
        # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
        :hermes_enabled => false
      )
      # Pods for Fomoyolo
      pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
      pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
      pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
      pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
      pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
      pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
      pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
      pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
      pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
      pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
      pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
      pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
      pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
      pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
      pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
      pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
      pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
      pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
    
      pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
      pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
      pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
      pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
      pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
      pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
      pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
    
      pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
      pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
      pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
      pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'
    
      pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    
      pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/google-signin'
    
    
      # pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
    
      use_native_modules!
    end
```

**New Podfile:**

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'Fomoyolo' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  # Enables Flipper.cd
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

At the end I have added `post_install` to force all libraries to install deployment 12.0.