# Having trouble installing Cocoapods on an obtained project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have received a project from a colleague that does not have the frameworks included in the files, I didn't think it would be that big of an issue as I have used Cocoapods in the past without ever running into any problems, however I am really having trouble with the install of these. Below is my Podfile and the error I am receiving when attempting to do a `pod install`. Can someone please tell me what is going wrong and give me some idea of how to fix it.

The error log:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/RCTVibration":
  In Podfile:
    React/RCTVibration (from `../node_modules/react-native`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/RCTVibration (from `../node_modules/react-native`)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `bestride` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`
```

The Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

project 'bestride.xcodeproj'

target 'bestride' do
    rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  
    # See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies
    pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
    pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
      'Core',
      'CxxBridge',
      'DevSupport',
      'RCTActionSheet',
      'RCTAnimation',
      'RCTGeolocation',
      'RCTImage',
      'RCTLinkingIOS',
      'RCTNetwork',
      'RCTSettings',
      'RCTText',
      'RCTVibration',
      'RCTWebSocket',
    ]
  
    # React Native third party dependencies podspecs
    pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
    pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
    # If you are using React Native <0.54, you will get the following error:
    # "The name of the given podspec `GLog` doesn't match the expected one `glog`"
    # Use the following line instead:
    #pod 'GLog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec"
    pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
  
    # react-native-maps dependencies
    pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path  # Uncomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
    pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Uncomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
    pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' # Uncomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
    pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~>4.42.0'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~>4.42.0'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~>4.42.0'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin'

    pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'

    pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

    pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

    pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

    pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'

    pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'
    pod 'react-native-date-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-date-picker'
    pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'

    pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

  end
  
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
        end
      end
      if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please check my answer for RN 0.64.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66998345/9673374

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point can be to run a `pod deintegrate` command.

In the past when I've had issues with CocoaPods, restarting my configuration from scratch resolved my errors.

You could try the following commands to start from a clean slate. Make sure to shelve your Pod file elsewhere so you can reference what frameworks you wanted to install.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod cache clean --all
$ rm Podfile
```

Then, follow up and perform:

```
pod install
pod update
```

Alternatively, you may have an issue with your node installation since you are using React, in which case I'd recommend referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917963/react-native-ios-podfile-issue-with-use-native-modules)

*Note: what could be happening is that your frameworks are simply out of date, and they may be cached in your system, thus linking to older mismatched references.*